# Failing heatmap in R

Tags: r

[image]I have a symmetrical matrix that I am trying to plot in R with a heatmap, but the output is not symmetrical. I created a small example matrix and created the heatmap:

```
>m
                       Name Hemolytic.activity Gelatinase
Name               0.000000          1.0037802  2.4336506
Hemolytic.activity 1.003780          0.0000000  0.4961328
Gelatinase         2.433651          0.4961328  0.0000000
```

The result of heatmap() is attached - same happens when I remove dendrograms with Colv = NA, Rowv = NA.
Am I doing something wrong? Loaded packages are:

```
library("xlsx")
library("arules")
library("arulesViz")
library("fastDummies")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I dont see any attachment

Comment: Sorry, added the image!

Answer (score 2):

With the following code I get a symmetrical heatmap. Is this that you're looking for?

A created a fast reproducible example. You can replace it with your data.

```
m <- cor(mtcars[1:5])
heatmap(m, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, symm = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So the difference is symm argument? What happens without, i.e. how can someone even represent a symmetrical matrix in any other way?

Comment: I would do it with a ggplot and geom_tile.. I can give you the code if you want to